# LINQ: Cannot get more than two Where clauses to work

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iqueryable

I cannot get the following to work properly. I want to search my database using more than 2 conditions where it will be possible to search only on one, two or all three, thus narrowing the search. At the moment, I can only get it to work with one condition at a time, and it only evaluates the first condition when having more than 3.

How can I Include more than 2 conditions? I have tried several proposed solutions from other sources, that uses if statements and where clauses, but so far none of them have worked.

This is my controller

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString, int searchProject, string searchTitel)
{
    var Projektdokumenter = from p in _context.ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype
    .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
    .Include(p => p.Dokuundertype)
    .Include(p => p.Forfatter)
    .Include(p => p.P)
    .Include(p => p.Sprog)
                            select p;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ^ searchProject != null ^ !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitel))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            var c = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.Forfatter.Initialer.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
            return View(c);
        }
        {
            if (searchProject != 0)
            {
                var d = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.P.ProjektId.Equals(searchProject)).ToList();
                return View(d);
            }
            {
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitel))
                {
                    var f = Projektdokumenter.Where(p => p.Titel.Contains(searchTitel)).ToList();
                    return View(f);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    var e = Projektdokumenter.Where(c.Contains(searchString) && p.P.ProjektId.Equals(searchProject) && p.Titel.Contains(searchTitel)).ToList();
    return View(e);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the C# `^` operator does? What do you think the `return` statement does?

Comment: @NetMage: give us a hint :-)

Comment: @monty I have no insight into what jackb77 thinks...

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable` can be combined, so just write in native way:

```cs
{
    var query = _context.ProjekterDokutypeDokuundertype
      .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
      .Include(p => p.Dokuundertype)
      .Include(p => p.Forfatter)
      .Include(p => p.P)
      .Include(p => p.Sprog)
      .AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Forfatter.Initialer.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (searchProject != 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.P.ProjektId == searchProject);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitel))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Titel.Contains(searchTitel))
    }

    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the OP did wrong with his code?